# Python: Using .format() on a Unicode-escaped string

Tags: python, string, unicode, python-2.x

I am using Python 2.6.5. My code requires the use of the "more than or equal to" sign. Here it goes:

```
>>> s = u'\u2265'
>>> print s
>>> ≥
>>> print "{0}".format(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<input>", line 1, in <module> 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2265'
  in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`
```

Why do I get this error? Is there a right way to do this? I need to use the `.format()` function.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Just make the second string also a unicode string

```
>>> s = u'\u2265'
>>> print s
≥
>>> print "{0}".format(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2265' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> print u"{0}".format(s)
≥
>>>
```

Comment: @Kit: If you want all literals to be Unicode (like in Python 3), put `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the beginning of your source files.

Comment: Yeah, this will get you if you're used to % formatting as this "%s" % u"\u2265" works, but "{}".format(u"\u2265") will throw an exception.

Comment: what a simple thing.. what a terrible headache i got until i found this bit of enlightenment..

Answer (score 73):

`unicode`s need `unicode` format strings.

```
>>> print u'{0}'.format(s)
≥
```

Answer (score 10):

A bit more information on *why* that happens.

```
>>> s = u'\u2265'
>>> print s
```

works because `print` automatically uses the system encoding for your environment, which was likely set to UTF-8. (You can check by doing `import sys; print sys.stdout.encoding`)

`>>> print "{0}".format(s)`

fails because `format` tries to match the encoding of the type that it is called on (I couldn't find documentation on this, but this is the behavior I've noticed).  Since string literals are byte strings encoded as ASCII in python 2, `format` tries to encode `s` as ASCII, which then results in that exception. Observe:

```
>>> s = u'\u2265'
>>> s.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2265' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So that is basically why these approaches work:

```
>>> s = u'\u2265'
>>> print u'{}'.format(s)
≥
>>> print '{}'.format(s.encode('utf-8'))
≥
```

> The source character set is defined by the encoding declaration; it is ASCII if no encoding declaration is given in the source file
>   (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

Comment: Oh and I found this to be of great help in understanding unicode in python, and text representation in computer systems  in general: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to have to chime in 10 years later, but it looks like folks missed the simple answer here... `str` format strings need `str` arguments. Wherein '≥' is perfectly acceptable: [since 2001](https://peps.python.org/pep-0263/) you can declare the source format. This lets you [use UTF-8 directly in your source code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289494/5896591):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print '{}'.format('≥')
```

Note that Python 3 drops `format()` and UTF-8 source support for byte strings, so consider switching to `%` and hex codes:

```
import sys
bprint = lambda s: sys.stdout.buffer.write(s + b"\n") and None
bprint(b'%s' % b'\xe2\x89\xa5')
```

(should you choose to port your program to Python 3 one day)