# Working with UTF-8 encoding in Python source

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Consider:

```
$ cat bla.py 
u = unicode('d…')
s = u.encode('utf-8')
print s
$ python bla.py 
  File "bla.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file bla.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

How can I declare UTF-8 strings in source code?

Comment: "See http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details" seems clear to me.

Answer (score 874):

In Python 3, UTF-8 is the default source encoding (see [PEP 3120](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/)), so Unicode characters can be used anywhere.

In Python 2, you can declare in the source code header:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
....
```

This is described in [PEP 0263](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/).

Then you can use UTF-8 in strings:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

u = 'idzie wąż wąską dróżką'
uu = u.decode('utf8')
s = uu.encode('cp1250')
print(s)
```

Comment: now it gives """UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)"""

Comment: You need not use `unicode()`, simply write string in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: In Python versions older than 3, you also need to prefix unicode string literals with "u": `some_string = u'idzie wąż wąską dróżką'`.

Comment: on a diffrent string I am getting """UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1845-1846: character maps to <undefined>"""... does that mean a different encoding is required?

Comment: or
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # coding: utf-8

Comment: Whole source code must be saved in UTF-8 encoding. Some text editors have 'Save As...' where you can also set encoding.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about coding: utf8 header? I can't see any explanation in your provided PEP page.

Comment: @Karolis, see the [Unicode Literals in Python Source Code](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-literals-in-python-source-code) section of the Python docs Unicode HOWTO

Comment: If you are reading from FILE you should consider using of codecs as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376923/reading-non-ascii-characters-from-a-text-file

Comment: Is it possible to have that as default system-wide? (when editing temporary short scripts for instance)

Comment: No, declaring is the only way I know. Many editors can use code templates so if you open new Python it is opened with code you like.

Comment: use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` or `# encoding: utf-8` ? oh, I think I found it: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: where is this source header file located?

Comment: I put it on the 2nd line of code. In 1st there is shebang.

Comment: @MichałNiklas I removed the `()` around `print` because it's a Python 2 code snippet and in Python 2 you don't use brackets for `print`. If you try to run that code on Python 3 you'll get this error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'.`.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy but Python 2 works very well with brackets in `print('wąż')`. You can see discusion on it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415181/brackets-around-print-in-python

Comment: that's pretty hacky

Answer (score 92):

Do not forget to verify if your text editor encodes properly your code in UTF-8.

Otherwise, you may have invisible characters that are not interpreted as UTF-8.

Comment: Is this needed for python3? I know python3 assumes all literals within the code are unicode. But does it assume the source files are also written in utf8?

Comment: @RicardoCruz Yes I believe utf-8 is the default for Python 3. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/

Comment: @ricardo-cruz *With Python 3, all strings will be Unicode strings, so the original encoding of the source will have no impact at run-time.* 

1. [PEP 3120 -- Using UTF-8 as the default source encoding](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3120/)
2. [PEP 263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: @noobninja thanks for the links: PEP 3120 confirms that the source code itself is now assumed to be UTF-8, not just strings.

Comment: Use `# coding: utf8` instead of  `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`which is far easier to remember.

Comment: @noobninja "the original encoding of the source will have no impact at runtime" is incorrect.  Unicode string *constants* require Python to know the encoding of the source file to properly generate the Unicode strings.  Python 3 assumes UTF-8 so `#coding` is required if the source is in another encoding and there are non-ASCII characters present.