# How do I split a multi-languages line in Python and get the Unicode hex value?

Tags: python, unicode, cjk, right-to-left

I try to split this kind of lines in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29):

> aiburenshi    爱不忍释    "לא מסוגל להינתק, לא יכול להיפרד מדבר מרוב חיבתו אליו"

This line contains Hebrew, simplified Chinese and English.

If I have a tuple T for example, I would like to get the tuple to be T= (Hebrew string, English string, Chinese string).

The problem is that I don't figure out how to get the Unicode value of the Chinese of the Hebrew letters. Both these lines don't work:

```
print ((unicode("释","utf-8")).encode("utf-8"))
print ((unicode("א","utf-8")).encode("utf-8"))
```

And I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe9' in file split_or.py on line 9, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Comment: It might be worth indicating the version of Python you are using (2.x or 3.x) either in the question, tags, or both.

Comment: Did you declare any encoding at the beginning of your file, such as #coding:utf-8?

Comment: The problem you state is a very clear erro that even contains the link to the text that tells you how to solve it. Why didn't you read the link? As a result, this is a duplicate of [working with utf-8 encoding in python source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source)

Comment: @LennartRegebro what are you talking about?

Comment: The error includes the text "see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details". That link tells you exactly how to fix the error you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, you need to open the file specifying an encoding like this:

```
import codecs
f = codecs.open("myfile.txt","r",encoding="utf-8")
```

In Python 3, you can just add the encoding option to any open() calls.

This will guarantee that the file is correctly decoded. Note that this doesn't mean your print calls will work properly, that depends on many things (see for example http://www.pycs.net/users/0000323/stories/14.html and that's just a start); it's better to either use a proper debugger, or output to a file (which will again be opened with codecs.open() ).

To get the actual codepoint (i.e. integer "value"), you can use the built-in ord():

```
>>> ord(u"£")
163
```

if you know the ranges for different languages, that's all you need. See [this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm) or [this page](http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fontsbyrange.html) for the ranges.

Otherwise, you might want to use `unicodedata` to look up stuff, like the bidirectional category:

```
>>> unicodedata.bidirectional(u"£")
ET  # 'E'uropean 'T'erminator
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, Unicode string constants need to be prefaced with the "u" character, as in:

```
print ((unicode(u"释","utf-8")).encode("utf-8"))
print ((unicode(u"א","utf-8")).encode("utf-8"))
```

In Python 3, string constants are Unicode by default.