# Reading non-ASCII characters from a text file

Tags: python, character-encoding

I'm using python 2.7. I've tried many things like codecs but didn't work. How can I fix this.

myfile.txt

```
wörd
```

My code

```
f = open('myfile.txt','r')
for line in f:
    print line
f.close()
```

Output

```
s\xc3\xb6zc\xc3\xbck
```

Output is same on eclipse and command window. I'm using Win7. There is no problem with any characters when I don't read from a file.

Comment: What result are you expecting? Technically speaking, python has read the file correctly.

Comment: Why do you print out the line character by character? Why not simply say `for line in f: print line`? When I did that, it printed "söcük" as desired.

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. It printed s\xc3\xb6zc\xc3\xbck.

Comment: Python is working just fine, the issue is the encoding in your terminal window / console.

Comment: where are u outputting? if it is a terminal, that might be the issue

Comment: Its same on eclipse and command window. I'm using Win7. There is no problem with any characters when I don't read from a file.

Comment: Are you sure that you are printing in a Windows 7 "Command Prompt" (black screen) and you actually see `s\xc3\xb6zc\xc3\xbck` printed just like that backslash x c 3 etc?? Really sure that you are doing `print line` and not `print repr(line)`???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. First of all - detect the file's encoding

```
  from chardet import detect
  encoding = lambda x: detect(x)['encoding']
  print encoding(line)
```

2. then - convert it to unicode or your default encoding str:

```
  n_line=unicode(line,encoding(line),errors='ignore')
  print n_line
  print n_line.encode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 16):

```
import codecs
#open it with utf-8 encoding 
f=codecs.open("myfile.txt","r",encoding='utf-8')
#read the file to unicode string
sfile=f.read()

#check the encoding type
print type(file) #it's unicode

#unicode should be encoded to standard string to display it properly
print sfile.encode('utf-8')
#check the type of encoded string

print type(sfile.encode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the terminal encoding. Try to configure your terminal with the same encoding you are using in your file. I recomend you to use UTF-8.

By the way, is a good practice to decode-encode all your inputs-outputs to avoid problems:

```
f = open('test.txt','r')    
for line in f:
    l = unicode(line, encoding='utf-8')# decode the input                                                                                  
    print l.encode('utf-8') # encode the output                                                                                            
f.close()
```

Comment: Now I see why they're making UTF-8 standard in 3.0. (PEP 3120)

Comment: @mgold: PEP 3120 is all about encoding of the source (.py) file; it's nothing to do with the OP's problem with encoding of input and/or output.