# problems of reading a collection of files including non-ascii characters

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to build word vectors using the following code segment

```
DIR = "C:\Users\Desktop\data\\rec.sport.hockey"
posts = [open(os.path.join(DIR,f)).read() for f in os.listdir(DIR)]
x_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(posts)
```

However, the code returns the following error message

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 240: invalid start byte
```

I think it is related to some non-ascii characters. How to solve this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376923/reading-non-ascii-characters-from-a-text-file

Comment: Make `DIR` unicode: `u"C:\Users\Desktop\data\\rec.sport.hockey"`

Comment: Hi Peter, I tried u"C:\Users\Desktop\data\\rec.sport.hockey". This returns error message like SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 0):

Is the file automatically generated? If not, one simple solution is to open the file with Notepad++ and convert the encoding to utf-8.

Comment: Hi Pourya, this is the 20 newsgroup data set I downloaded from internet. The related directory given above has about 1000 files. I even do not know which file has this problem. If there are a lot of files have this kind of problem, how to solve it? Thanks.