# Check if a string contains "pålogget" - unicode error

Tags: unicode, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am playing around with screenscraping with BeautifulSoup on a Norwegian site. I need to check if a string contains the word *"Pålogget"* (meaning logged on).

```
if "Pålogget" in status:
```

I get the following error

> File "scrape.py", line 23
>   SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file scrape.py on line 23, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

How can I do this?

Comment: duplicate of [working with utf-8 encoding in python source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

to the beginning of your file.

Comment: It would still be better to explicitly mark the string as Unicode with `u"Pålogget"`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Tommyka should do both. The coding line will tell the compiler to interpret the file using UTF-8 encoding (civilized editors will get it automatically, but YMMV) and the "u" prefix will let the compiler know that what follows is not a sequence of bytes, but a unicode string. Using only the prefix or only the coding may lead to unintender results.

Comment: You should also mention to **save** the file in UTF-8.

Comment: It worked like a charm!
I tried earlier with u"Pålogget" but need the file encoding.