# brackets around print in python

Tags: python, printing

I have this line of code in python

```
print 'hello world'
```

against

```
print ('hello world')
```

can someone tell me the difference between the two?

I used it in a a simple code

```
var = 3
if var > 2: 
    print 'hello'
```

it fails for checking strictly for all values for var. But if I define the code as

```
var = 3
if var > 2: 
    print ('hello')
```

it works!

Comment: Your final two snippets are not valid Python code. Please don't post such code as it's hard to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: http://ramblings.timgolden.me.uk/2010/07/02/python-3-print-or-print/ and http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#what-s-new-in-python-3-0

Comment: @larsmans Not sure what you mean; they are perfectly valid (except for the fact that the print statement does not exist in Python 3).

Comment: @poke Both are missing the colon after the `if`. This means the code was typed anew without much attention into SO and the structure of the original code might be something completely different. The indent of the `if` is also invalid - an indent **must** follow a statement that opens a block. So, no, the code samples aren't even close to valid.

Comment: @millimoose I can see colons…?

Comment: @poke Ah. That's an edit then. (SO hides edits done quickly after posting the question from history.) The original code was rather jumbled.

Answer (score 16):

For Python 2, it makes no difference. There, `print` is a statement and `'hello'` and `('hello')` are its argument. The latter gets simplified to just `'hello'` and as such it’s identical.

In Python 3, the print statement was removed in favor of a print function. Functions are invoked using braces, so they are actually needed. In that case, the `print 'hello'` is a syntax error, while `print('hello')` invokes the function with `'hello'` as its first argument.

You can backport the print function to Python 2, by importing it explicitly. To do that add the following as the first import of your module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Then you will get the same behaviour from Python 3 in Python 2, and again the parentheses are required.

Answer (score 9):

You should read [what's new in python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#what-s-new-in-python-3-0):

> The print statement has been replaced with a `print()` function,
>   with keyword arguments to replace most of the special syntax of the
>   old print statement ([PEP
>   3105](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)).

[**Backwards Compatibility**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/#backwards-compatibility):

> The changes proposed in this PEP will render most of today's print
>   statements invalid. Only those which incidentally feature parentheses
>   around all of their arguments will continue to be valid Python syntax
>   in version 3.0, and of those, only the ones printing a single
>   parenthesized value will continue to do the same thing. For example,
>   in 2.x:

```
>>> print ("Hello", "world")  # without import
('Hello', 'world')

>>> from __future__ import print_function  

>>> print ("Hello", "world")       # after import 
Hello world
```

Comment: @hayden: It won't unless you import print_function from future

Comment: @Abhijit Not true; the parentheses for the print statement in Python 2 are ignored. Just in the same way they are ignored in `print ((((('test')))))`.

Comment: @hayden: In python, using parenthesis around an expression is optional, unless you are invoking a callable (a function or a class). In python 2, `print` is a statement, so anything following the `print` statement is an expression and that makes the parenthesis optional there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `print('test')` works fine in Python 2.7.3... apologies this was the only thing I was referring to

Comment: @hayden but `print('test','test')` will return a tuple in 2.x.

Comment: @hayden: exactly, that's what I am saying. The parenthesis are part of the expression following the `print` statement. They are *not* interpreted as a call to a `python` function. Ashwini is quite right in pointing out that adding a comma would make that a *tuple*, not multiple arguments to the `print` function.

Answer (score 1):

I landed here on my search for regex to convert these syntaxes. Here is my solution for others:

Works well in old Python2 example scripts. Otherwise use 2to3.py for additional conversions.

Try it out on Regexr.com (doesn't work in NP++ for some reason):

```
find:     (?<=print)( ')(.*)(')
replace: ('$2')
```

for variables:

```
(?<=print)( )(.*)(\n)
('$2')\n
```

for label and variable:

```
(?<=print)( ')(.*)(',)(.*)(\n)
('$2',$4)\n
```

[How to replace all print "string" in Python2 with print("string") for Python3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917898/how-to-replace-all-print-string-in-python2-with-printstring-for-python3/53917912#53917912)