# plotting a graph in an xml file

Tags: matplotlib, networkx

I want to show the graph using the python code below, but I am getting a syntax error as seen on the image. Please help to correct this error. I am using Python 3

```
import os
import sys
import fnss
import networkx as nx
import fnss
import cvxopt
import numpy as np
import codecs
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
topo_str = 'topo_peter.xml'
topology = fnss.read_topology(topo_str)
topology_directed = topology.to_directed(topology)
print nx.info(topology_directed)
nx.draw(topology_directed)
plt.show()
```

and this is the am getting

> ```
> File "<ipython-input-1-fa7157dd7268>", line 14
> print nx.info(topology_directed)
>       ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: It's generally a better idea to include your code directly in your post than to post an image of it. Remember that you can use the built-in formatting tools to make the code snippet show up as a snippet. Make sure to only include the parts of your code that are relevant to the error you're seeing!

Comment: Are you using python 2.7 or 3.x?

Comment: @joel python 3.7

Comment: Change `print nx.info(topology_directed)` to `print(nx.info(topology_directed))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [brackets around print in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415181/brackets-around-print-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided:

```
Python version: 3
Error message: invalid syntax on line 14 -> print nx.info(topology_directed)
```

It is clearly a simple `syntax error` for people using Python 3 to execute a Python 2 statement.

```
print "something"  # is valid for Python 2, but not Python 3
```

For Python 3, use

```
print("something", "and more", "even more")
```

So changing `print nx.info(topology_directed)` to `print(nx.info(topology_directed))` solves the problem.