# How am I able to use python print() function in 2.7.12?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I know that the `print` is a function in **Python 3** and a statement in **Python 2**. Found it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function)

I tested local and online interpreters with below code

**In Python 3:**

`print('test')` - working fine

`print 'test'` - throwing error

**In Python 2:**

`print('test')` - working fine

`print 'test'` - working fine

My question is that if the print is a statement and not a function in **Python 2**, isn't it supposed to throw a syntax error when we use `print` function?

Why is it still working in **Python 2** when we use `print` function?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13415304/5012099)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`('test')` is a valid expression in any version of Python; the parentheses just act as a grouping for multiple expressions, of which there's only one here, so they're superfluous.

`print('test')` in Python 2 is the same as `print ('test')` is the same as `print (('test'))` is the same as `print 'test'`.