# jpype - diactric signs cause UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: java, python, unicode, jpype

I've recently started using jpype and it worked nice so far but when I tried to pass a string with polish diacritic sings (ą,ć,ó - stuff like that) as a parameter it throws UnicodeDecodeError.

Even java.lang.System.out.println("Mąka") throws UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Is there a way around it? Using diacritic signs is crucial for this app....

Comment: You need the utf-8 encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source

Comment: thanks, I forgot to add 'utf-8' as a parameter to decode() :D