# Correct way to hash password with Non-ASCII characters in Python 2.7

Tags: python, hash, ascii, md5

What is the correct and/or standard way of creating password hashes from user input when this user input does include also non ascii characters ?

I have noticed that when I generate MD5 hashes using only ASCII chars I always get the same result. But lets say user want's his/hers password to be 'pöllö' (Owl, in English).

Here is an example from a few online MD5 hash generators generating a hash for pöllö

http://www.md5hashgenerator.com/index.php
Hash: 0cbe7f5ca855599480e4313e63e8093d

http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php
Hash: 0f6b1c5d67c201eb1c3c37300b8be077

Comment: This is a question of charset. Your first website uses iso-8859-15, the second one utf-8. The first is used for East European languages (almost) only but uses a 8 bits code, where utf-8 suits all languages in the world (or tries to) but characters may be coded on 8 to 32 bits each.

Answer (score 0):

Use the md5 class in the  [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) module

Answer (score 0):

In python, this should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import  hashlib

m = hashlib.md5()
m.update("pöllö")
print(m.hexdigest())
```

The comments on top is a source header declaration to be able to use non ascii characters. (src-- [Working with utf-8 encoding in Python source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source))