# file encoding issues with eclipse pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, encoding, utf-16

I have been building a calculator with a GUI in python and finished, and I went back to update stuff and simplify the coding and know I am running into text encoding issues. I had them fixed and had everything set to UTF-16 and it was working just fine. I cam back now and I am getting this error:

```
File "D:\Documents\Scripts\Python\Calculator\Calculator\CalculatorGUI.pyw", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xfe' in file D:\Documents\Scripts\Python\Calculator\Calculator\CalculatorGUI.pyw on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Now \xfe is now where in my code, and it was working before. So I don't know what could have changed. If you need to see the whole script, comment, and I will post it all.

Thanks

EDIT: Per request, here is the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B35OsPAJ46kvZXl2OTN3Y19IOUE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source

Comment: probably upload the script somewhere ... dont copy and paste or we might not see the same bytes

Comment: @shavenwarthog I already declared the encoding type and I am still getting the same problem

Comment: @JoranBeasley script uploaded

Comment: did you open it with something other than eclipse at some point? it seems to have a funny encoding for sure ...

Comment: you probably need to convert the file to utf8 (notepad++ can do this easily ..., that seemed to work for me)

Comment: @JoranBeasley that worked, thanks a lot. Do you mind posting that as an answer so I can close the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably need to convert the file to utf8 (notepad++ can do this easily ..., that seemed to work for me)