# "SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character" in running Python code

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

Im starting with python and when i use the interpreter and run this code:

```
>>>peliculas = ["movie1", "movie2", "movie3", "movie4"]
>>>print(peliculas[1])
```

when i use Pycharm IDE it doesnt compile:

```
peliculas = ["movie1", "movie2", "movie3", "movie4"]
print(peliculas[1])
```

This is the output:

```
 File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/Prueba2.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /Users/user/PycharmProjects/untitled/Prueba2.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

What´s wrong with python?.. do i installed it correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Working with utf-8 encoding in Python source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source)

Comment: Typing out the whole thing at a stretch. When you copy-paste things in unicode, they stay in unicode, and don't get converted to ASCII. In this case, you have unicode quotes

Comment: I typed everithing, how to fix by default this issue?

Comment: Did you actually _look_ at http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html as the error suggested, before coming here? If not, why not? Maybe you should stop watching those weird Euro-movies with their umlaut-y titles and other funny accented characters, like those in "Óscar López", whose answer you should read :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo in pycharm?

Comment: anon, the error has a blink (hey, if everyone else can shorten web-log to blog, surely I can shorten web-link to blink) that it suggests you go look at. You would use a browser for that.

Answer (score 9):

Just add these two lines at to top of python code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Answer (score 7):

It's a file encoding problem. Try adding this at the beginning of the file:

```
#coding=utf-8
```

Comment: or `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm you can specify file encoding via the **File | File encoding** menu, or the file encoding item on the status bar. See [this help article](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-individual-file-encoding.html#status)