# Writing CSV file with umlauts causing "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character"

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to write characters with double dots (umlauts) such as ä, ö and Ö. I am able to write it to the file with `data.encode("utf-8")` but the result `b'\xc3\xa4\xc3\xa4\xc3\x96'` is not nice (UTF-8 as literal characters). I want to get `"ääÖ"` as written stored to a file.

**How can I write data with umlaut characters to a CSV file in Python 3?**

```
import csv
data="ääÖ"
with open("test.csv", "w") as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=";")
    data=resultFile
    a.writerows(data)
```

Traceback:

```
File "<ipython-input-280-73b1f615929e>", line 5, in <module>
  a.writerows(data)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe4' in position 15: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Does it help to open the file with `encoding='utf-8'`?

Comment: try to add: `#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source)

Comment: @languitar no, it did not.

Comment: @terencehill that is not the issue here, `encoding` parameter needed to be added in the open function as instructed by yper. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Actually this doesn't work with python2X and do you realised that the solution given by yper is exactly the same as suggested by @languitar above? Anyway with python3 the solution accepted it's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a parameter `encoding` to the `open()` and set it to `'utf8'`.

```
import csv

data = "ääÖ"
with open("test.csv", 'w', encoding='utf8') as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=";")
    a.writerows(data)
```

Edit: Removed the use of `io` library as `open` is same as `io.open` in Python 3.

Comment: You can set encoding in `open` too

Comment: In Python 3, `open` and `io.open` are the exact same thing. It's only in Python 2 where they differ (where `io.open` behaves like Python 3 `open`).

Comment: This solution works with python3 on my OSX but gives the error with python2.7. The error is in the line when data is set so before the call to open and the specification of the encoding.

Answer (score -1):

This solution should work on both python2 and 3 (not needed in python3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
data="ääÖ"
with open("test.csv", "w") as fp:
    a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=";")
    a.writerows(data)
```

Credits to:
[Working with utf-8 encoding in Python source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source)