# Non UTF-8 code Error when I run a flask application with a debug mode

Tags: python, flask

I am running the simple flask application. The python file is like the followings.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def Welcome():
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')

@app.route('/myapp')
def WelcomeToMyapp():
    return 'Welcome again to my app running on Bluemix!'

@app.route('/api/people')
def GetPeople():
    list = [
        {'name': 'John', 'age': 28},
        {'name': 'Bill', 'val': 26}
    ]
    return jsonify(results=list)

@app.route('/api/people/<name>')
def SayHello(name):
    message = {
        'message': 'Hello ' + name
    }
    return jsonify(results=message)

port = os.getenv('PORT', '5000')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(port))
```

And I set the environmental variables like the followings.

```
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
set FLASK_APP=welcome.py
flask run
```

But I got the error like the followings.

```
D:\workspace\github\pytyon-flask-sample>flask run
 * Serving Flask app "welcome"
 * Forcing debug mode on
 * Restarting with stat
  File "D:\ide\python-3.5\Scripts\flask.exe", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x90' in file D:\ide\python-3.5\Scripts\flask.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Comment: This should resolve that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source

Comment: I should have written for me to tried it already. Besides I am using python 3.

Comment: Did you try setting an encoding like UTF-32 just to see if it fixed it?

Comment: You mean, instead of writing UTF-8, You want me to write using UTF-32??

Comment: I mean at the top just specify `# -*- coding: utf-32 -*-`

Comment: Even if I tried it, it gave the same error.

Comment: A quick look through stack for `\x90` indicates this may be an issue with how you are running your script, rather than the contents.

Comment: @DylanLawrence I got the different error D:\workspace\github\pytyon-flask-sample>flask run
Cannot open D:\ide\python-3.5\Scripts\flask-script.py