# Python 3 character encoding issue

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

i am selecting values from a MySQL // Maria DB that contains latin1 charset with latin1_swedish_ci collation. There are possible characters from different European language as Spanish ñ, German ä or Norwegian ø.

I get the data with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

...
sql.execute("SELECT name FROM myTab")
for row in sql
 print(row[0])
```

There is an error message:
*UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf1'*
 Okay I have changed my print to

```
print(str(row[0].encode('utf8')))
```

and the result looks like this:
    b'\xc3\xb1'
i looked at this [Working with utf-8 encoding in Python source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source) but i have declard the header. Also `decode('utf8').encode('cp1250')` does not help

Comment: thanks for supporting. this returnes `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 0`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set sys.stdout encoding in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay the encoding issue has been solved finaly. Coldspeed gave a important hind with loacle. therefore all kudos for him! Unfortunately it was not that easy.

I found a workaround that fix the problem.

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open(sys.stdout.fileno(), mode='w', encoding='utf8', buffering=1)
```

The solution is from [Jack O'Connor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/823869/jack-oconnor). posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374455/how-to-set-sys-stdout-encoding-in-python-3/33470043#33470043):

Comment: +1 as this has allowed me to move forward.   However, shouldn't this be written in flashing lights at the top of somewhere like https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html?   My issue relates to using a jinja2 template.  Where the template doesn't contain any unicode everything is OK, however, once there is a single unicode character somewhere in the template it breaks.  My system locale is 'en_US.UTF-8' and no amount of encode/decode solved the problem.  But the above just feels like such a fundamental thing that it cannot be the "correct way"?

Comment: A thousand time this! How is this not the default in 2018 :/

Answer (score 1):

Python3 tries to automatically decode this string based on your locale settings. If your locale doesn't match up with the encoding on the string, you get garbled text, or it doesn't work at all. You can forcibly try encoding it with your locale and then decoding to `cp1252` (it seems this is the encoding on the string).

```
print(row[0].encode('latin-1').decode('cp1252'))
```

Comment: seems the point with locale directs to the goal. unfortunately your approach still does not brings the correct solution. But with locale i am getting closer.

Comment: @JoePlatano what about `row[0].encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')`?

Comment: no does not work, well it does on shell if i exec the script as python script.py it works. On the webserver not. I added the following lines `print(sys.stdout.encoding)`and `print(sys.getdefaultencoding())` in shell there is utf-8 for both. if i execute the script on browser there is ANSI_X3.4-1968 for sys.stdout.encoding and utf-8 for sys.getdefaultencoding(). I think there is some locale issue on apache

Comment: @JoePlatano Oh, I see... afraid I'm at a loss here. Hope you figure it out! You should try different encodings and see which works.

Comment: yeah thanks anyway for pushing me in a good direction! Therefore the upvote. Thanks buddy