# python encoding issue Raspberry

Tags: python, encoding, raspberry-pi, sys

I'm having a problem using sys.argv[] to pass some values to a Python script.

My Python script is like that:

---

```
#Obtención de los valores provenientes del servidor
referencia = sys.argv[1] #referencia velocidad

referencia = int(referencia)
```

---

In the lx terminal I execute the next command:

```
$sudo python referencia.py 2750
```

And the terminal gives me the next error:

```
File "referencia.py", line 11
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file referencia.py on line 11, but no encoding declared: see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Has anyone one solution to execute my script without errors?

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source
It's not the input, but the source code (ó)

Answer (score 1):

It complains about the "ó" in "Obtención" in the comment, try to avoid using "special characters" in your files or specify the encoding you're using. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for documentation.