# Get unicode error when attempting to save file

Tags: python, python-docx

I am trying to save a **python-docx** document in **Ubuntu**, but I get this error: `'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xed' in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)`. I tried to apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20), but I get this other error: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'write'`.

This is the code that raised the first error:

```
current_directory = settings.MEDIA_DIR
file_name = "Rooming {} {}-{}.docx".format(hotel, start_date, end_date)
document.save(current_directory + file_name)
```

This is the code that raised the latest error:

```
current_directory = settings.MEDIA_DIR
file_name = "Rooming {} {}-{}.docx".format(hotel, start_date, end_date)
document.save((current_directory + file_name).encode('utf-8'))
```

I know the file name will end having non standard ascii characters, but I would like to be able to save the files using all those characters.

Comment: try using `file_name = r"Rooming {} {}-{}.docx".format(hotel, start_date, end_date)`

Comment: @prashant rana, Nope, same error

Comment: That example was for python 2.x, and I suspect you are using 3.x. What does `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` say? Also, consider adding an example of your first try so we can keep them separate In fact, that second one could be removed completely.

Comment: @tdelaney I added the code for the first try. `sys.getfilesystemconding()` returns `'utf-8'`

Comment: @HugoLuisVillalobosCanto have you tried this? [Working with utf-8 encoding in Python source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289494/1248974)

Comment: Try `docx.Document().save(file_name)` - that will narrow the problem to the file name or the document itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem raised because in Spanish we use some characters modifiers that are not standard (áéíóúüñ), and I was trying to form the name of the file with some data that includes such characters. I guess there must be a way to configure the server so this wouldn't be an issue, but I took the short path and changed the special characters for their standard base character:

```
current_directory = settings.MEDIA_DIR
file_name = "Rooming {} {}-{}.docx".format(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', hotel).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'), start_date, end_date)
document.save(current_directory + file_name)
```

This method replaces characters like this: `áéíóúüñÁÉÍÓÚÜÑ -> aeiouunAEIOUUN`.

The error desaparead.