# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character error

Tags: python, csv, apache-spark, unicode, pyspark

I am reading some files from google cloud storage using python

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('aggs').getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.option("sep","\t").option("encoding", "UTF-8").csv('gs://path/', inferSchema=True, header=True,encoding='utf-8')
df.count()
df.show(10)
```

However, I keep getting an error that complains about the `df.show(10)` line:

```
df.show(10)
File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 
350, in show
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 162: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I googled and found this seems to be a common error and the solution should be added in the encoding of `"UTF-8"` to the `spark.read.option`, as I already did. Since this doesn't help, I am still getting this error, could experts help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: which python version?

Comment: @frankegoesdown Python version 2.7

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` add this string as 1st row to your file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source

Comment: @frankegoesdown I added that line to the first line of my py, and still get this same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about exporting [`PYTHONIOENCODING`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) before running your Spark job:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
```

For **Python 3.7+** the following should also do the trick:

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

For **Python 2.x** you can use the following:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Comment: This should work. `df.show()` uses the good old `print` function, which will try to encode the output data to whatever you system default is before piping it to stdout.     Make sure you set this environment variable before starting the python interpreter.

Comment: @Giorgos Myrianthous. Hi, I did the export and I've checked using sys.stdin.encoding; sys.stdout.encoing; sys.stderr.encoding, they all output "utf-8". However, I am still getting the same error as before. Maybe I should do more?

Comment: @Kevin How about `import sys` `reload(sys)` `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` ?