# How do I fix an unusual SyntaxError in the python executable itself when running line_profiler?

Tags: python, python-2.7, line-profiler

Here's a strange one.

First of all: **This is NOT a problem with the encoding of a python script file that I have written myself or am importing** (see e.g. [Working with UTF-8 encoding in Python source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source) and the many duplicates thereof).

I am running the excellent [line_profiler](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler) over some python2.7 code in a virtual env. The SyntaxError is pointing to the python executable itself! So obviously(?) I can't add an encoding line at the top.

Is this perhaps an issue with line_profiler? Otherwise how on earth to proceed?

Here is the traceback:

```
(myenv)$ kernprof -l python main.py
Wrote profile results to python.lprof
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[snip]/myenv/bin/kernprof", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "[snip]/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kernprof.py", line 226, in main
    execfile(script_file, ns, ns)
  File "[snip]/myenv/bin/python", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xcf' in file [snip]/myenv/bin/python on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Comment: OK the answer is simply to add #!/usr/bin/env python to main.py and rather execute kernprof -l ./main.py. Hey presto!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to make `main.py` executable, i.e. add the shebang to the top:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

And `chmod +x main.py` - then:

```
kernprof -l ./main.py
```

Who knew!