# how to solve below pivoting table scenario in python? rows are converting into columns with respect to field names

Tags: python

1st table is my input table present in 1 data frame and 2nd table is my result table. can some one please help how to solve this using python
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJzgW.jpg

Comment: Hey there, I would like you to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and go through [how do I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make the necessary changes. Its always a good practice to show your research so far and work related to the question if necessary as opposed to asking the community to write the code based on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df.groupby('Hr')[['Apps',  'Record_Count', 'Records_Per_Sec']].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Apps').T.unstack())
```

---

```
Apps    A                                   B                                   C
        Record_Count    Records_Per_Sec     Record_Count    Records_Per_Sec     Record_Count    Records_Per_Sec
Hr                      
0-1     60              1                   60              1                   60              1
```

Comment: @Pygirl-- Thanks.. I have tried with this code but getting below error
ERROR --- > PEP 263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings.
What T refers to in lamda code part?

Comment: ERROR --- > PEP 263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings.

Comment: The issue is with your data. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289494/6660373 please follow the solution. For the data you have provided this is the solution that I have given.

Comment: Encoding error resolved and attribute error df1 = df.groupby('Hr'),['Apps','record_count','Records_per_sec'].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Apps').T.unstack())..... getting below error.
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'

Comment: Add the dataframe and the whole traceback to the post.. btw syntax is wrong. Please check your syntax. Why there is comma after groupby('Hr')

Comment: df = tableitem.select("Hr","Apps", "record_count", "Records_per_sec")

Error:
df1 = df.groupby('Hr')[['Apps','record_count','Records_per_sec']].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Apps').T.unstack())
TypeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Can you show me what exactly you are doing? Because I can't see the problem with the solution provided on the given data. Invite me in chat and show me the screenshot.