# Decoding utf-8 in Django while using unicode_literals in Python 2.7

Tags: django, unicode, utf-8, python-2.7

I'm using Django to manage a Postgres database.  I have a value stored in the database representing a city in Spain (Málaga).  My Django project uses unicode strings for everything by putting `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the beginning of each of the files I created.

I need to pull the city information from the database and send it to another server using an `XML` request.  There is logging in place along the way so that I can observe the flow of data.  When I try and log the value for the city I get the following traceback:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe1' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here is the code I use to log the values I'm passing.

```
def createXML(self, dict):
    """
    ..  method:: createXML()

        Create a single-depth XML string based on a set of tuples

        :param dict: Set of tuples (simple dictionary)
    """

    xml_string = ''
    for key in dict:
        self.logfile.write('\nkey = {0}\n'.format(key))
        if (isinstance(dict[key], basestring)):
            self.logfile.write('basestring\n')
            self.logfile.write('value = {0}\n\n'.format(dict[key].decode('utf-8')))
        else:
            self.logfile.write('value = {0}\n\n'.format(dict[key]))

        xml_string += '<{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(key, dict[key])

    return xml_string
```

I'm basically saving all the information I have in a simple dictionary and using this function to generate an `XML` formatted string - this is beyond the scope of this question.

The error I am getting had me wondering what was actually being saved in the database.  I have verified the value is `utf-8` encoded.  I created a simple script to extract the value from the database, decode it and print it to the screen.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import psycopg2
# Establish the database connection
try:
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname = 'dbname' \
                           user = 'user' \
                           host = 'IP Address' \
                           password = 'password'")
    cur = db.cursor()
except:
    print "Unable to connect to the database."

# Get database info if any is available
command = "SELECT state FROM table WHERE id = 'my_id'"
cur.execute(command)
results = cur.fetchall()

state = results[0][0]
print "my state is {0}".format(state.decode('utf-8'))
```

Result: `my state is Málaga`

In Django I'm doing the following to create the HTTP request:

```
## Create the header
http_header = "POST {0} HTTP/1.0\nHost: {1}\nContent-Type: text/xml\nAuthorization: Basic {2}\nContent-Length: {3}\n\n"
req = http_header.format(service, host, auth, len(self.xml_string)) + self.xml_string
```

Can anyone help me correct the problem so that I can write this information to the database and be able to create the `req` string to send to the other server?

Am I getting this error as a result of how Django is handling this?  If so, what is Django doing?  Or, what am I telling Django to do that is causing this?

EDIT1:
I've tried to use Django's `django.utils.encoding` on this state value as well.  I read a little from [saltycrane](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/11/python-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character/) about a possible hiccup Djano might have with unicode/utf-8 stuff.

I tried to modify my logging to use the `smart_str` functionality.

```
def createXML(self, dict):
    """
    ..  method:: createXML()

        Create a single-depth XML string based on a set of tuples

        :param dict: Set of tuples (simple dictionary)
    """

    xml_string = ''
    for key in dict:
        if (isinstance(dict[key], basestring)):
            if (key == 'v1:State'):
                var_str = smart_str(dict[key])
                for index in range(0, len(var_str)):
                    var = bin(ord(var_str[index]))
                    self.logfile.write(var)
                    self.logfile.write('\n')
                self.logfile.write('{0}\n'.format(var_str))

        xml_string += '<{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(key, dict[key])

    return xml_string
```

I'm able to write the correct value to the log doing this but I narrowed down another possible problem with the `.format()` string functionality in Python.  Of course my Google search of `python format unicode` had the first result as [Issue 7300](http://bugs.python.org/issue7300), which states that this is a known "issue" with Python 2.7.

Now, from [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235386/python-using-format-on-a-unicode-escaped-string) I found a "solution" that does not work in Django with the `smart_str` functionality (or at least I've been unable to get them to work together).

I'm going to continue digging around and see if I can't find the underlying problem - or at least a work-around.

EDIT2:
I found a work-around by simply concatenating strings rather than using the `.format()` functionality.  I don't like this "solution" - it's ugly, but it got the job done.

```
def createXML(self, dict):
    """
    ..  method:: createXML()

        Create a single-depth XML string based on a set of tuples

        :param dict: Set of tuples (simple dictionary)
    """

    xml_string = ''
    for key in dict:
        xml_string += '<{0}>'.format(key)
        if (isinstance(dict[key], basestring)):
            xml_string += smart_str(dict[key])
        else:
            xml_string += str(dict[key])
        xml_string += '<{0}>'.format(key)

    return xml_string
```

I'm going to leave this question unanswered as I'd love to find a solution that lets me use `.format()` the way it was intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct approach (problem was with opening file. With UTF-8 You MUST use `codecs.open()` :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import codecs


class Writer(object):
    logfile = codecs.open("test.log", "w", 'utf-8')

    def createXML(self, dict):
        xml_string = ''
        for key, value in dict.iteritems():
            self.logfile.write(u'\nkey = {0}\n'.format(key))
            if (isinstance(value, basestring)):
                self.logfile.write(u'basestring\n')
                self.logfile.write(u'value = {0}\n\n'.format( value))
            else:
                self.logfile.write(u'value = {0}\n\n'.format( value ))

            xml_string += u'<{0}>{1}</{0}>'.format(key, value )

        return xml_string
```

And this is from python console:

```
In [1]: from test import Writer

In [2]: d = { 'a' : u'Zażółć gęślą jaźń', 'b' : u'Och ja Ci zażółcę' }

In [3]: w = Writer()

In [4]: w.createXML(d)
Out[4]: u'<a>Za\u017c\xf3\u0142\u0107 g\u0119\u015bl\u0105 ja\u017a\u0144</a><b>Och ja Ci za\u017c\xf3\u0142c\u0119</b>'
```

And this is `test.log` file:

```
key = a
basestring
value = Zażółć gęślą jaźń


key = b
basestring
value = Och ja Ci zażółcę
```