# Formatting a non english string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have written a function which needs to format a string that contains Hebrew letters, the script runs perfectly when using english letters. But when using Hebrew ones, it gives me the following error:

The error is:

```
Error:  'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

function code is (the code under define line is indented and not as seen in the code block):

```
def postWP(gameTitle,gameCode):
    print "PostWP activated, Title: %s" % gameTitle
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('email@gmail.com','emailPassword')
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(gameTitle, gameCode)
    print "Sending mail..."
    mail.sendmail('email@gmail.com','destination@mail.com',message)
    mail.close()
```

Basically, the problem occurs at `'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(gameTitle, gameCode)'`.

I was wondering how can I get it fixed. Thanks in advance to everyone who is trying to help!
Best Regards, have a great day!

Comment: Just use the `unicode` format string: `message = u'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(gameTitle, gameCode)` (notice the `u`). Better yet, switch to Python3 and you won't have to worry about Unicode strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Using .format() on a Unicode-escaped string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235386/python-using-format-on-a-unicode-escaped-string)

Comment: Have you tried put the following at the beginning of the file? # -\*- coding: utf8 -\*-

Comment: You're going to find this very difficult to get right if you don't use Python's email-handling modules.

Comment: @JackYang Yes, I have written that at the beginning of the file, thanks.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams why? It works perfectly, just the string formatting makes issues. using mime with text file does the error as well.

Comment: @randomir  I have already viewed that post, it didn't help me.

Comment: @Nadav, the problem is solved by using a `unicode` format string (as in the question I linked). See my first comment.

Comment: @randomir thanks for the quick response, I've tried it and it didn't work as well. I have now tried using the unicode function to make the variables unicode as well, trying it out right now.

Comment: `def postWP(gameTitle,gameCode):
 print "PostWP activated, Title: %s" % gameTitle
 mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
 mail.ehlo()
 mail.starttls()
 mail.login('email','password')
 message = u'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(unicode(gameTitle), unicode(gameCode))
 print "Sending mail..."
 mail.sendmail('email@gmail.com','emailhere',unicode(message))
 mail.close()`
still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

```
def postWP(gameTitle,gameCode):
    # additional parameter checking
    if not isinstance(gameTitle, basestring):
        print "gameTitle type error"
        return
    if not isinstance(gameCode, basestring):
        print "gameCode type error"
        return
    if isinstance(gameTitle, unicode):
        gameTitle = gameTitle.encode('utf8')
    if isinstance(gameCode, unicode):
        gameCode = gameCode.encode('utf8')

    # the following remains the same
    print "PostWP activated, Title: %s" % gameTitle
    mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    mail.ehlo()
    mail.starttls()
    mail.login('email@gmail.com','emailPassword')
    message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(gameTitle, gameCode)
    print "Sending mail..."
    mail.sendmail('email@gmail.com','destination@mail.com',message)
    mail.close()
```

Comment: Still does not work.
`PostWP activated, Title: ╫ש╫ץ╫ñ╫ש ╫₧╫ó╫ש╫ף╫ƒ ╫פ╫נ╫ס╫ƒ
Error:  'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Could you post the gameTitle and gameCode when the failure happens?

Comment: it occurs for example when gameTitle="מייפל סטורי" and gameCode='<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.example.com/media/528g1a3f51341Maple-Story-SV3.swf" width="800" height="600">'

Comment: Since here gameCode is not an instance of basestring, which is either str or unicode, it should print "gameCode type error" and return. Are you really running the program with that inputs?

Comment: Yes I am.. it gives me the following error when using the code you have written:
`Error:  'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "girlgames.py", line 124, in <module>
    print "Error: ", format(er)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 86-89: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: I ran it with your input of gameTitle and gameCode without any error. From the error message, it errors at line 124, which seems a lot longer program than posted. Is it possible it errors at some places other than the one you posted?

Comment: Lines 123-124 are an exception, the error there is probably due to hebrew letters which should be in the error.  `except Exception as er:
  print "Error: ", format(er)`