# Logging fails with UnicodeEncodeError when attempting to use .format(myVar) where myVar contains unicode characters

Tags: python-2.7

I am using the str.format() function in my logging:

```
    logging.debug('querying author: {}, track: {}'.format(artist)
```

When the artist variable contains unicode characters such as this: `u'Ry Cooder & Ali Farka Tour\xe9'` format fails as follows:

```
    artists = {u'A Tribe Called Quest': [u"People's Instinctive Travels and the Paths of Rhythm"],
     u'All': [u'Percolater', u'Pummel'],
     u'Andrew Bird': [u'The Mysterious Production of Eggs',
                      u'Noble Beast',
                      u'Break It Yourself',
                      u'Weather Systems',
                      u'Hands of Glory'],
     u'April Smith And The Great Picture Show': [u'Songs For A Sinking Ship'],
     u'Ry Cooder & Ali Farka Tour\xe9': [u'Talking Timbuktu']}

    for each in artists:
        print 'this is the string: u"{}"'.format(each)

    >>> this is the string: A Tribe Called Quest
    >>> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    >>> UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
    >>> <ipython-input-28-4770333e9fbf> in <module>()
    >>>       1 for each in artists:
    >>> ----> 2     print 'this is the string: {}'.format(each)

    >>> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 26: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is the proper way to deal with this for all logging instances? I know that I can use `str.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` to dump the unicode characters and side-step this issue as such:

```
    for each in artists:
        print 'this is the string: {}'.format(each.encode('ascii', 'ignore'))

    >>> this is the string: A Tribe Called Quest
    >>> this is the string: Ry Cooder & Ali Farka Tour
    >>> this is the string: Andrew Bird
    >>> this is the string: All
    >>> this is the string: April Smith And The Great Picture Show
```

The above solution would mean hunting down every logging instance that might encounter unicode characters and adding str.encode() and that doesn't feel very "pythonic."

**EDIT 10 Jan2 2019**

This is especially problematic when another module's logging attempts to deal with this data. Other than make sure that the unicode characters never make it out of my controlled environs, is there another solution?

**end EDIT**

Is there a more elegant and appropriate way to deal with this? What is the appropriate way to handle unicode when using the str.format() function?

For completeness:

The artist variable is always forced to unicode using the following code as the API I am interacting with requires UTF-8.

```
        def _forceUnicode(self, text):
            '''
            force text into unicode
            https://gist.github.com/gornostal/1f123aaf838506038710
            '''
            return text if isinstance(text, unicode) else text.encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235386/python-using-format-on-a-unicode-escaped-string) solution using `u'logger text {}'.format(artist)`, but it's very similar to the encode() solution described above and requires editing every. single. logging line.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with the `u'{}'` solution, you may as well change all of your logging to unicode.  Using one or the other probably won't cause problems, but mixing unicode and regular strings gets tricky.

Comment: Would it be more pythonic to write a superclass of str() and add a .logformat() method? I can find/replace all the log lines, it just seems like there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL:DR: `text.encode('utf-8')` should be `text.decode('utf-8')` and the `str.format()` statements should be preceded by "u" as in `u'some text: {}'.format(myVar)`.

**Long Answer:**
I fundamentally did not understand the difference between 'utf-8' and 'unicode.' I can't say that I fully understand it now, but I realize now that my attempt to force all my text to unicode was actually forcing it to utf-8 and `str.format()` was choking on the utf-8 that I was feeding it.

The function above ***should read***:

```
        def _forceUnicode(text):
            '''
            force text into unicode
            https://gist.github.com/gornostal/1f123aaf838506038710
            '''
            return text if isinstance(text, unicode) else text.decode('utf-8')
```

That forces everything into unicode and `str.format()` behaves as expected but requires an indication that it is a unicode string `print u'{}'.format()`:

```
    for each in artists:
        print u'this is the string: {}'.format(each)

    >>> this is the string: A Tribe Called Quest
    >>> this is the string: Ry Cooder & Ali Farka Touré
    >>> this is the string: Andrew Bird
    >>> this is the string: All
    >>> this is the string: April Smith And The Great Picture Show
```