# How to make `format` function in python 2 to work with `unicode` type objects with UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, utf-8

I have huge code base with lots of `format` functions. I want to pass `unicode` type objects as arguments like:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
x = u"ñö"
print isinstance(x,unicode)#prints "True"

y = "Hello {0}".format(x)# "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)"
print y
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Using .format() on a Unicode-escaped string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235386/python-using-format-on-a-unicode-escaped-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me without changing every line where `format` is used:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Basically I had problems whenever `"string {}"` in `"string {}".format("hello")` was `str` object. Writing a simple `u"string {}"` would have helped, but huge code base remember? `"hello"` doesn't really matter.

Answer (score -1):

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
x = r"ñö"
print isinstance(x,unicode)#prints "True"

y = "Hello {0}".format(x)# "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)"
print y
```

Comment: I get the value x from somewhere which I can't change.

Comment: You may want to improve your answer by adding a short explanation of the essential part. The mission of Stack Overflow is to build a knowledge base. Your main audience consists of future readers.